# Getting User Data by using Guards (Roles, JWT)

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, nestjs

The documentation is kinda thin here so I ran into a problem. I try to use Guards to secure Controller or it's Actions, so I gonna ask for the role of authenticated requests (by JWT). In my auth.guard.ts I ask for "request.user" but it's empty, so I can't check the users role. I don't know how to define "request.user". Here is my auth module and it's imports.

**auth.controller.ts**

```
import { Controller, Get, UseGuards } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AuthGuard } from '@nestjs/passport';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';
import { RolesGuard } from './auth.guard';

@Controller('auth')
export class AuthController {
  constructor(private readonly authService: AuthService) {}

  @Get('token')
  async createToken(): Promise<any> {
    return await this.authService.signIn();
  }

  @Get('data')
  @UseGuards(RolesGuard)
  findAll() {
    return { message: 'authed!' };
  }
}
```

**roles.guard.ts**

Here user.request is empty, because I never define it. The documentation doesn't show how or where.

```
import { Injectable, CanActivate, ExecutionContext } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Reflector } from '@nestjs/core';

@Injectable()
export class RolesGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(private readonly reflector: Reflector) {}

  canActivate(context: ExecutionContext): boolean {
    const roles = this.reflector.get<string[]>('roles', context.getHandler());
    if (!roles) {
      return true;
    }
    const request = context.switchToHttp().getRequest();
    const user = request.user; // it's undefined
    const hasRole = () =>
      user.roles.some(role => !!roles.find(item => item === role));
    return user && user.roles && hasRole();
  }
}
```

**auth.module.ts**

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';
import { HttpStrategy } from './http.strategy';
import { UserModule } from './../user/user.module';
import { AuthController } from './auth.controller';
import { JwtStrategy } from './jwt.strategy';
import { PassportModule } from '@nestjs/passport';
import { JwtModule } from '@nestjs/jwt';

@Module({
  imports: [
    PassportModule.register({ defaultStrategy: 'jwt' }),
    JwtModule.register({
      secretOrPrivateKey: 'secretKey',
      signOptions: {
        expiresIn: 3600,
      },
    }),
    UserModule,
  ],
  providers: [AuthService, HttpStrategy],
  controllers: [AuthController],
})
export class AuthModule {}
```

**auth.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { UserService } from '../user/user.service';
import { JwtService } from '@nestjs/jwt';

@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
  constructor(
    private readonly userService: UserService,
    private readonly jwtService: JwtService,
  ) {}

  async signIn(): Promise<object> {
    // In the real-world app you shouldn't expose this method publicly
    // instead, return a token once you verify user credentials
    const user: any = { email: 'user@email.com' };
    const token: string = this.jwtService.sign(user);
    return { token };
  }

  async validateUser(payload: any): Promise<any> {
    // Validate if token passed along with HTTP request
    // is associated with any registered account in the database
    return await this.userService.findOneByEmail(payload.email);
  }
}
```

**jwt.strategy.ts**

```
import { ExtractJwt, Strategy } from 'passport-jwt';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';
import { PassportStrategy } from '@nestjs/passport';
import { Injectable, UnauthorizedException } from '@nestjs/common';

@Injectable()
export class JwtStrategy extends PassportStrategy(Strategy) {
  constructor(private readonly authService: AuthService) {
    super({
      jwtFromRequest: ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken(),
      secretOrKey: 'secretKey',
    });
  }

  async validate(payload: any) {
    const user = await this.authService.validateUser(payload);
    if (!user) {
      throw new UnauthorizedException();
    }
    return user;
  }
}
```

Documentation: https://docs.nestjs.com/guards

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Additionally to your `RolesGuard` you need to use an `AuthGuard`.

#### Standard

You can use the standard `AuthGuard` implementation which attaches the user object to the request. It throws a 401 error, when the user is unauthenticated.

```
@UseGuards(AuthGuard('jwt'))
```

#### Extension

If you need to write your own guard because you need different behavior, extend the original `AuthGuard` and override the methods you need to change (`handleRequest` in the example):

```
@Injectable()
export class MyAuthGuard extends AuthGuard('jwt') {

  handleRequest(err, user, info: Error) {
    // don't throw 401 error when unauthenticated
    return user;
  }

}
```

---

#### Why do this?

If you look at the [source code](https://github.com/nestjs/passport/blob/6d9c71fa04e5c16480ba0b7e7671e43918dd9ff4/lib/auth.guard.ts) of the `AuthGuard` you can see that it attaches the user to the request as a callback to the passport method. If you don't want to use/extend the `AuthGuard`, you will have to implement/copy the relevant parts.

```
const user = await passportFn(
  type || this.options.defaultStrategy,
  options,
  // This is the callback passed to passport. handleRequest returns the user.
  (err, info, user) => this.handleRequest(err, info, user)
);
// Then the user object is attached to the request
// under the default property 'user' which you can change by configuration.
request[options.property || defaultOptions.property] = user;
```

Comment: It works since I use @UseGuards(AuthGuard('jwt'), RolesGuard) as decorator. I extending AuthGuard for my RolesGuard and overwriting the functions, but it's seems they don't get called.

Comment: I'm glad it's working now. :-) I think from a single responsibility perspective it makes sense to have them separate. If you still wanted to extend in your case, you would probably want to override `canActivate(...)` and then call `super.canActivate(...)` from within.

Comment: As a general question, a guard is not supposed to have a single responsability and are not intended to modify the request object?, dont we have interceptors/middlewares for that?. Is a good/normal practice to inject values inside the guard? @KimKern

Answer (score 9):

You can attach multiple guards together (@UseGuards(AuthGuard('jwt'), RolesGuard)) to pass the context between them. Then you will have access 'req.user' object inside 'RolesGuard'.

Answer (score 2):

After I got the selected answer working (thank you), I found this option as well that you can add to the constructor that essentially does the same thing.

http://www.passportjs.org/docs/authorize/

> **Association in Verify Callback**
>
> One downside to the approach described above is that it requires two
> instances of the same strategy and supporting routes.
>
> To avoid this, set the strategy's passReqToCallback option to true.
> With this option enabled, req will be passed as the first argument to
> the verify callback.

```js
    @Injectable()
    export class LocalStrategy extends PassportStrategy(Strategy, 'local') {
    
        constructor(private authService: AuthService) {
            super({
                passReqToCallback: true
            })
        }

        // rest of the strategy (validate)
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Does it work if you use `req.authInfo`?

As long as you don't provide a custom callback to passport.authenticate method, the user data should be attached to the request object like this.

`req.authInfo` should be the object you returned in your `validate` method